# Can the xxhash seed be found given a large set of hashes?

Tags: hash

xxhash clearly states that it's non-cryptographic, but I have had trouble comprehending what this practically means. Does this mean that the seed and/or input could be reconstructed given a very large number of hashes?

(Assume the seed is a random 8 bytes of data and the input itself can not be guessed either by hand (although the input values are related))

Answer (score 1):

A cryptographic hash has several properties (from Wikipedia) :

- it is quick to compute the hash value for any given message
- it is infeasible to generate a message from its hash value except by trying all possible messages
- a small change to a message should change the hash value so extensively that the new hash value appears uncorrelated with the old hash value
- it is infeasible to find two different messages with the same hash value

A hash function like xxhash doesn't need those properties - it is intended for things like hashtables and instead looks for sheer speed and good distribution of values.

One note : by "it is quick to compute the hash value for any given message" for a cryptographic hash, they really mean it is PRACTICAL rather than quick.  One of the problems with MD5 (which was considered a cryptographic hash, but now is considered broken) is that it has reached the point where brute forcing short passwords is practical, because GPU based clusters can do ten billion tries a second or so. That isn't all that is broken about MD5 - there are some mathematical attacks on the hash as well, but it doesn't help. Bcrypt/scrypt/SSHA512 all are much, much slower, but still practical for normal usage.